# Unable to remove Aurelia routing's preceding hashtag

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve.
It should be possible to remove the preceding hashtag in routes by executing the steps provided in `RouterConfiguration -> Options-> Push State`.

I've executed all these steps, see the code below.

**app.ts RouterConfiguration options**

```
public configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.options.root = '/';
    config.map([
        {
            route: 'login',
            name: 'login',
            moduleId: 'pages/auth/login',
            nav: false,
            title: 'Login',
            settings: {
                allow_anonymous: true
            }
        }
    ]);
    ...
```

**index.html head**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  ...
```

**config.js**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  ...
```

My login route still only works using `localhost:9000/#/login` whereas `localhost:9000/login` can't be found.
I've also tried implementing this in a fresh Aurelia JSPM skeleton application to no avail...

Any idea why this is happening and what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'll point someone from the router team to look at this.

Comment: What you are showing works fine for a long time for me, can you push up a repro with the fresh skeleton you mentioned?

Comment: @PWKad sure, here is the fresh Aurelia JSPM skeleton repo => https://github.com/bryandh/aurelia-routing-no-hash 
The welcome route only works when I enter `localhost:9000/#/welcome`. The route then visually changes to `localhost:9000/welcome` but when i physically refresh that page/route or navigate to the URL manually the route can't be found.

Comment: What you describe is a server configuration issue. For all your routes which normally follow after the `#`, you need to configure your server to serve the main `index.html`. The app is then bootstrapped and will handle the URLs `/welcome`.

Comment: @MarcScheib I used Express and didn't have to configure anything 0.o

Comment: @8protons Probably it is configured ready to use for an SPA. Do you use some special package or express directly? Anyway, how should a server know to serve `index.html` on nearly all routes (except API)? It may configured as a fallback, however, normally you would expect a 404. Or your 404 redirect is the `index.html`.

Comment: How do I configure the server to accept there URLs then @MarcScheib ? I have configured JSPM to use the baseURL "/".

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: I'm running it locally with BrowserSync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BrowserSync (as described by @Bryandh), you need to configure it to always fallback to your `index.html`. Depending on your project, you may have some task file(e.g. a Gulp serve task, which is used throughout Aurelia) which needs to be changed.

As an example, I took Aurelia's skeleton navigation project. It has a sub directory `skeleton-esnext` which uses Gulp and JSPM to run the application. In the file `build/tasks/serve.js` is a `serve` task which needs to be adjusted as follows:

```
var historyFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', ['build'], function(done) {
  browserSync({
    online: false,
    open: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.'],
      middleware: [function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        next();
      }, historyFallback()]
    }
  }, done);
});
```

The important part is the `historyFallback()` middleware. This is provided automatically by BrowserSync. If you serve your app with this task now (`gulp serve` or `gulp watch`), you can directly access your routes, e.g. `http://localhost:9000/users`. There will be no more 404 as you get directed to `index.html` which bootstraps Aurelia and handles the route `/users`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm! I had absolutely no idea I could do this, appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0):

For my views that are being dynamically loaded into the router-view container, with index as the root, I was able to get my project's URLs to look like the following (which I believe is what you're asking for):

- `http://localhost:2112/`
- `http://localhost:2112/jobs`
- `http://localhost:2112/discussion`

I didn't need to alter as much code as you shared in order to get this to work. The first thing I did was to establish a base reference in my root html file.
 For me, this was *index.html*.

`<base href="/" />`

Then, I set the push state to `true` inside the `configureRouter()` method

```
configureRouter(config, route) {
   ...
   config.options.pushState = true;
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly as I described in my question, so this unfortunately doesn't really help me any further.

Comment: @Bryandh This answer is not "exactly as [you] described in [your] question". You have extraneous steps- I only wrote two lines of code to get this to work. You changed a significant more than simply two lines, including altering `config.js`, which may be causing your issue. I would advise you to start over and literally do what my answer suggests. Good luck.